# Google maps turn-by-turn voice navigation with android api

Tags: android, google-maps

I am interested in integrating Google turn by turn navigation with voice API (similar to google navigation app) into my application. I have searched a lot but couldn't find a concrete example. Any example or pointer is really appreciated it.

Regards,
Jawad

Comment: No one will spoon feed you answers, Post your problems on the implementation you did, don't ask for implementation itself. I am sure about google maps Android SDK has a very good documentation and great example on the github repo. as well you can find links to it on the documentation itself. Good Luck

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39066317/how-we-can-read-google-maps-turn-by-turn-navigation-instructions

Answer (score 0):

You may not find a good free solution for in-app navigation APIs. If you're willing to pay, Mapbox is one good option: https://www.mapbox.com/navigation/

They provide some code samples in their test app for the SDK on github:
https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-android#sample-code

I don't work for the company, and I haven't used Mapbox myself, but I've heard good things from others who have used it.